# How to map source to target property?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Lets say I have two POJOs.
The source class:

```
class CustomerSource {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String houseNumber;
  private String postcode;
}
```

and target class:

```
class CustomerAddresses {
  private CustomerTarget customer;
  private List<Address> addresses;

  class CustomerTarget {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
  }

  class Address{
    private String houseNumber;
    private String postcode;
  }
}
```

So I want to map it using Mapstruct but I can't find a decent way to do it. As of now, the only way is to do this:

```
@Mapping(target = "customer.firstname", source = "firstname")
@Mapping(target = "addresses", expression = "java(Collections.singletonList(toAddress(customer)))")
CustomerAddresses toTarget(CustomerSource customer);
```

So the question is **how to map** `CustomerSource` into `CustomerAddresses.customer` field without manually declaring each field.
**Secondary question**: is there any way to NOT use expression for this `Address` to `List` of addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map `CustomerSource` to `CustomerAddresses.Customer` without declaring mapping for each field, you can declare a method that performs mapping, which would be used by the initial method.

```
CustomerAddresses.CustomerTarget toCustomerTarget(CustomerSource customerSource);
```

Similarly, to map `CustomerSource` to `List<CustomerAddresses.Address>` define a default method that creates a list.

```
default List<CustomerAddresses.Address> toAddressList(CustomerSource customerSource) {
  return Collections.singletonList(toAddress(customerSource));
}
```

Finally, to point Mapstruct to use the aforementioned methods, declare `toTarget` method as shown below, where `.` means that the whole object is passed to the underlying method.

```
@Mapping(source = ".", target = "addresses")
@Mapping(source = ".", target = "customer")
CustomerAddresses toTarget(CustomerSource customer);
```